# How to Find the Last Week's Most Sold Books in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build an online bookstore for my homework.
I want to list the most sold books by time (last week, last month, all time).
I wrote the all time query but couldn't figure the last week query.
Can someone please help me?

Here is the table:

```
TbSoldBooks (saleID, BookID, SaleDate)
```

(I searched but can't find the answer)

Update: This is for all time most sold books.

```
SELECT b.bookID, COUNT(b.bookID) AS All-Time  
FROM TbSoldBooks b  
GROUP BY b.bookID
```

Comment: Where are the queries you have tried so far?

Comment: I think you should spend more time writing queries on the database to get a feel for SQL, and less time searching on line for "the" answer. It's a toy database, SELECT statements won't break the data, and you have a great opportunity to really learn SQL skills.

Comment: @AhmetEmre90: That looks reasonable. Now you just need to modify that query with a `WHERE` query that specifies an appropriate SaleDate.

Comment: @AdamV I know but how can I compare time

Comment: Since SO won't let me edit just a few things in your statement, I guess I'll put it in a comment. All-Time (which you changed from All Time, good job) should probably be enclosed in brackets `[All Time]` or `[AllTime]`. As @AdamV just noted, you should put a `WHERE` clause in there (above `GROUP BY`) to filter the dates.

Comment: @AhmetEmre90: You need to find a way of using the current date to find the appropriate start and end dates of "last week" and "last month", and then you can use `WHERE` and `BETWEEN` to get appropriate SaleDate values.

Comment: @Adam I agree except I strongly recommend against BETWEEN. https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common.aspx & https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mishandling-date-range-queries.aspx

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I can't disagree with that! Can't edit my comment now though. Future readers: read Aaron's blog posts and avoid BETWEEN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT top 10 b.bookID, COUNT(b.bookID) 
FROM TbSoldBooks b  
GROUP BY b.bookID
Where SaleDate >= DateAdd(day, -7, getDate()) -- last week
Order by 2 desc

SELECT top 10 b.bookID, COUNT(b.bookID) 
FROM TbSoldBooks b  
GROUP BY b.bookID
Where SaleDate >= DateAdd(month, -1, getDate()) -- last month
Order by 2 desc
```

Comment: I would personally recommend against ordering using ordinals instead of column names: [link](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/06/bad-habits-to-kick-order-by-ordinal)

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't want to ruin *all* your homework for you, but you could try to `GROUP` by BookID and to `COUNT` the sales for each book.

EDIT:  I see you're confused about comparing dates. Take a look at [`DATEADD`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_dateadd.asp), then.

Comment: toss in a `WHERE` clause and this is a great answer